# MS Bot Framework / Facebook Account Linking and Messenger Extensions integration

Tags: facebook, botframework, azure-ad-b2c

We would like to enable the following scenario :

- user can login to a web application leveraging Azure AD B2C as the identity provider.
- user can also interact with a bot on FB messenger (built on MS Bot Framework). He is asked to log in so that we can get him an access token for subsequent web api calls.
- user has access to a persistent menu on his FB messenger where he can navigate to some pages of the actual web site and be logged in straight away.

I have the following question :

Could Azure AD B2C be used in conjunction with Facebook Account Linking ? Could not find any samples... What I am doing now : in the FB login button, I pass a link to one of my bot server controller method as a level of indirection. Then in this method, I get the redirect Uri and account linking token that FB is adding to the url and then do a redirect to my B2C policy url passing these 2 arguments in the state and my own redirect Uri (not the one from FB). This way, once authentication is done, b2c redirects to my bot where I rebuilt the callback to fb url. Any security concern with this approach?

Thx !

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this post [Facebook Messenger: get access token of linked account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883605/facebook-messenger-get-access-token-of-linked-account)  it seems that FB account linking is not really useful in regards to access token. I was expecting similar behavior as Amazon Alexa account linking but in fact it has nothing to do with exchanging an authorization code with an access token and having this token manage by FB... So I am just going to leverage the BotAuth code https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth to store the access token in the bot state... I dont really care about collecting the PSID...

Regarding the last step of the scenario, we are investigating cookies reuse from the first authentication flow.

Comment: OAuth support is now built into the Bot Framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Comment: Thanks Eric, will have a look indeed.